# ServletException while downloading files

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets, apache-poi

I was trying to implement a download function. The project was organized in Springframework. After the jsp form being submitted, records will be queried from DB first, and the record would be written into a NEW EXCEL file. Finally the excel file would be downloaded.

Related jsp codes:

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="javascript:searchList();">
 <input ></input>
    …
</form>

function searchList(){
 …
 $.ajax({
    url:”report/search”,
    type:”POST”,
    cache:false,
    data: {xxx:xxx},
    success:function(obj){
      if (obj){
         $.messager.alert(‘INFO’,obj.msg);
      }
    },
    error:function(ajaxErrObj){
     $.messager.alert(‘Error’, ajaxErrObj.status);
    }
  });
}
```

Related Java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object search(@RequestParam(“xxx”) String xxx, HttpServletResponse response
) {
try (OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(); Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();){
    Sheet oifSheet = wb.createSheet(“results”);

    //… generate content  

    String fileName = PRE_FILENAME + "_" + DateUtils.getDate(new Date().toString());
    response.reset();
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".xlsx");
    wb.write(out);
    wb.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    dataResult.setErrorCode(0);
    dataResult.setMsg("success”);
    return dataResult;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    dataResult.setErrorCode(1);
    dataResult.setMsg(“Error1”);
    return dataResult;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    dataResult.setErrorCode(1);
    dataResult.setMsg(“Errors ！”);
    return dataResult;
}
}
```

When a test the function. I would see “success” info on the web page. However
1. NO FILE was actually downloaded although the codes were executed(tracked by logger)
2. ServletException was thrown as:

```js
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/WEB-INF/views/report/search.jsp&quot; not found
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:412)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:160)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at com.alibaba.druid.support.http.WebStatFilter.doFilter(WebStatFilter.java:123)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

/report/search was the URL I used to call the service, why it turned out to be a file(/filepath)?
How to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your View Resolver. Check your View Resolver. You might be using XML based configuration or Annotation based configuration.